# How to find blood relatives only in prolog

Tags: prolog

Using recursion i need to find all blood relatives of any person in the family tree.
My attempt so far has failed.
Here is my code, with my attempt at the bottom

```
female(helen).
female(debbie).
female(louise).
female(yvonne).
female(belinda).
female(heather).
male(john).
male(andrew).
male(barry).
male(daniel).
male(charles).
parent(helen, debbie).
parent(helen, barry).
parent(helen, louise).
parent(john, debbie).
parent(john, barry).
parent(andrew, louise).
parent(debbie, yvonne).
parent(debbie, daniel).
parent(barry, charles).
parent(barry, belinda).
parent(louise, heather).

mother(X, Y) :-
        female(X),
        parent(X, Y).
father(X, Y) :-
        male(X),
        parent(X,Y).
child(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X).
daughter(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X),
        female(X).
son(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y,X),
        male(X).
sister(X, Y) :-
        female(X),
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y).
brother(X, Y) :-
        male(X),
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y).
sibling(X, Y) :-
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y),
        X\=Y.
uncle(X, Y) :-
        parent(P,Y),
        brother(X,P).
aunt(X, Y) :-
        parent(P,Y),
        sister(X,P).

cousin(C, Cousin):-
        parent(Parent,C),
        sibling(Parent,AU),
        child(Cousin,AU).

        %Here is Relative

relative(An, Re):-
        An\=Re,
        parent(An, Re);
        sibling(An, Re).

relative(An, Rela):-
        parent(An, Child);
        sibling(An, Rela),      
        relative(Child, Rela),
        An\=Rela, C\=Rela.
```

Sort of works, but gets stuck in an infinite loop at the end.
Thanks.

Comment: What did you query to cause the infinite loop?

Comment: relative(yvonne,X). Returns Daniel, and then nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

not sure about 'relatives' (any person bound reachable in a parent/child relation ?), but your definition seems more complex than needed ( do you know what `;` does ?).

I tried

```
relative(An, Re):-
        parent(An, Re).
relative(An, Rela):-
        parent(An, C),
        relative(C, Rela).
```

that yields

```
16 ?- forall(relative(X,Y),writeln(X:Y)).
helen:debbie
helen:barry
helen:louise
john:debbie
john:barry
andrew:louise
debbie:yvonne
debbie:daniel
barry:charles
barry:belinda
louise:heather
helen:yvonne
helen:daniel
helen:charles
helen:belinda
helen:heather
john:yvonne
john:daniel
john:charles
john:belinda
andrew:heather
true.
```

*edit* I tried another relation, using a generalized parent/2, but still too permissive.

```
relative(Pers, Re):-
        ancestor(Re, Pers) ; sibling(Pers, Re) ; cousin(Pers, Re) ; uncle(Re, Pers) ; aunt(Re, Pers).

ancestor(Anc, Pers) :- parent(Anc, Pers).
ancestor(Anc, Pers) :- parent(Anc, P), ancestor(P, Pers).
```

Maybe cousin/2 is too permissive also. Here is the graph

[image]

I guess that heather should have only luise,helen,andrew as relatives. It's this true ?

*edit* given latest comment, seems that the definition could be right. I get

```
24 ?- setln(X,relative(heather,X)).
andrew
barry
belinda
charles
daniel
debbie
helen
louise
yvonne
true.
```

that is everyone is related to heather apart john.

Comment: This definition of `relative` only provides ancestral/descendant relationships. It doesn't do siblings, cousins, etc. I think the OP is looking for the whole set of pairings of blood-line relatives.

Comment: @mbratch: I agree, it's too naive. Maybe going to uppermost ancestor and finding all descendants ?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting and straight-forward approach that could help keep it deterministic.

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty sure ; is "OR" therefore the idea was parent or sibling. However finding all the descendants does sound like a good idea. I just don't really know how to do it.
Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tried, but it results in *everyone* being relative (not what we expect!)

Comment: Heather should be related to everybody apart from John (By Blood). Andrew = grandfather. Helen = Grandmother. Louise = Mother. Belinda, charles, daniel, yvonne = Cousins. Louise & Debbie = Aunts. Barry = Uncle.
In fact most names will be pulled up however for yvonne, Andrew will not be when its done correctly.

Comment: @mbratch: yes, I wrote on that line, but didn't liked the code to find the older_parent. And then I didn't inspected sufficiently the test data (had still to produce the graph). And I think the current approach is more similar at 'real world' speaking of family, so maybe more useful.

Comment: I like your approach CapelliC. I took my own stab at it which looks simple enough but I'm not totally satisfied with.

Comment: By the looks of it, your second edit has cracked it. For Yvonne, it returns all but Andrew, with duplicates which are inevitable. Seems ok to me. Thanks! I'll keep testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that works, but it will sometimes produce duplicates. Using setof will give the unique collection. I avoided the miscellaneous relations and stuck with `descendent` or `parent`.

```
descendent(A, B) :-
    parent(B, A).
descendent(A, B) :-
    parent(C, A),
    descendent(C, B).

relative(A, B) :-
    descendent(B, A).
relative(A, B) :-
    descendent(A, B).
relative(A, B) :-
    descendent(A, C),
    descendent(B, C),
    A \= B.

setof(A, relative(heather, A), Relatives).

Relatives = [andrew,barry,belinda,charles,daniel,debbie,helen,louise,yvonne]
```

If you don't have `setof`, you can use the `findall/3` and `sort/2` ISO predicates:

```
findall(A, relative(heather, A), R), sort(R, Relatives).
```

Note that the solutions presented so far assume that all of the relatives have unique names. A general case of dealing with relatives with the same first name (and possibly the same last name) you would need to track and compare lineages for differences.

Comment: So I tried this, but setof isn't recognised by JIProlog, the program that we have to use. Any idea how I can fix this? Presumably nothing as simple as a using / include statement in C based languages :(

Comment: @Sizza apologies, as `setof` isn't an ISO predicate. However, you can get the same result using `findall/3` followed by `sort/2`, which I have added to my answer. Those are ISO predicates which I believe JIProlog will support.

Comment: @Sizza: `setof/3` is ISO! But JIProlog is not ISO. [Summary of ISO standard](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo).