# in Prolog How to Design a set of predicates that encode genealogical relationships

Tags: prolog

I am new in prolog , I need help please to how to design a set of predicates that encode genealogical relationships.

```
• male(X) - X is male.
• female(X) - X is female.
• parent(X,Y) - X is the parent of Y.
• mother(X,Y) - X is the mother of Y.
• father(X,Y) - X is the father of Y.
• child(X,Y) - X is the child of Y.
• sibling/2 (reflexive)
• grandparent(X,Y) - X is the grandparent of Y.
• grandmother(X,Y) - X is the grandmother of Y.
• grandfather(X,Y) - X is the grandfather of Y.
• grandchild(X,Y) - X is the gradchild of Y.
• grandson(X,Y) - X is the grandson of Y.
• granddaughter(X,Y) - X is the granddaughter of Y.
• uncle(X,Y) - X is the uncle of Y.
• aunt(X,Y) - X is the aunt of Y.
• cousin/2 (reflexive)
• ancestor(X,Y) - X is an ancestor of Y.
• descendant(X,Y) - X is a descendant of Y.
```

> Note: Your definitions should avoid infinite recursion and return a
>   single result set. For example, siblings(X,Y) should queries should
>   return a single result set, i.e. not X=bob,Y=joe; X=joe, Y=bob.
>
> Note: The Knowledge Base of people below is for example only. You are
>   just responsible for the definitions of predicate rules. The Knowledge
>   Base used for grading will be different.

here example and I only have problem with the last example

```
% Knowledge Base
male(adam).
male(bob).
male(brett).
male(charles).
male(chris).
male(clay).
female(ava).
female(barbara).
female(betty).
female(colette).
female(carrie).
parent(adam,bob).
parent(adam,barbara).
parent(ava,bob).
parent(ava,barbara).
parent(bob,clay).
parent(barbara,colette).

?- mother(ava,Kid)
Kid = bob;
Kid = barbara.

?- sibling(X,Y).
X = bob,
Y = barbara;

?- grandparent(GParent,colette).
GParent = adam;
GParent = ava.
```

this what I have

```
male(adam).
male(bob).
male(brett).
male(charles).
male(chris).
male(clay).
female(ava).
female(barbara).
female(betty).
female(colette).
female(carrie).
parent(adam,bob).
parent(adam,barbara).
parent(ava,bob).
parent(ava,barbara).
parent(bob,clay).
parent(barbara,colette).

mother(X, Y) :-
        female(X),
        parent(X, Y).
father(X, Y) :-
        male(X),
        parent(X,Y).
child(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X).
daughter(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y, X),
        female(X).
son(X, Y) :-
        parent(Y,X),
        male(X).
sister(X, Y) :-
        female(X),
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y).
brother(X, Y) :-
        male(X),
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y).
sibling(X, Y) :-
        parent(Q,X),
        parent(Q,Y),
        X\=Y.
uncle(X, Y) :-
        parent(P,Y),
        brother(X,P).
aunt(X, Y) :-
        parent(P,Y),
        sister(X,P).

cousin(C, Cousin):-
        parent(Parent,C),
        sibling(Parent,AU),
        child(Cousin,AU).

        %Here is Relative

relative(An, Re):-
        parent(An, Re).
relative(An, Rela):-
        parent(An, C),
        relative(C, Rela).
```

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. That's not what this site is about. Please write your own code and then ask us when your code doesn't work and you need help.

Comment: OK, so what's wrong with your current code that you need help with?

Comment: @Enigmativity when I tried the example I receive error , this my example.  ?- mother(ava,Kid) Kid = bob; Kid = barbara.  ?- sibling(X,Y). X = bob, Y = barbara;  ?- grandparent(GParent,colette). GParent = adam; GParent = ava.

Comment: Where you see an error? The queries in Prolog have multiple solutions in general. The single solution is just the special case.  Here is that you need I hope: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857072/how-to-find-blood-relatives-only-in-prolog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find blood relatives only in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857072/how-to-find-blood-relatives-only-in-prolog)  which was first noted by Anton Danilov

Comment: @user8286060 Of course you'll get an error if you try `mother(ava, Kid)` since you haven't defined `mother/2`. What error are you getting with `sibling(X, Y)` and `grandparent(GParent, colette).` queries?

Comment: @AntonDanilov I fixed my code and  I only have error in the last example ?- grandparent(GParent,colette).

Comment: @lurker you can check my code now, I fixed my code and all the example working good with me except the last example ?- grandparent(GParent,colette).

Comment: Where is your definition of `grandparent/2`?

Comment: @lurker I tried a lot but I keep receiving error , I don't know how to use GParent

Comment: Well, `grandparent(GParent, GChild) :-...` means `GParent` is the grandparent of `GChild` if.... *If what?*

Comment: @lurker I did it like this....    grandparent(G,N) :-
         parent(G,X),
         parent(X,N).                                                                                         and I received the result that I want but after the result it's say false

Comment: After successfully finding the results you want, if Prolog thinks there may be more choices (a choice point), it will search for more. If it can't find any more, it says `false` (or `no`). That's normal.